# Retaining maximum possible accuracy on float interpolation

Tags: c, floating-point, interpolation

We know that points X1 and X2 have respective points Y1 and Y2, so we can calculate Y for any X with:

```
 X - X1    Y - Y1
------- = -------
X2 - X1   Y2 - Y1
```

We can get simple formula (A) out of that:

```
Y = (X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) + Y1;
```

This should be mathematically equivalent (B):

```
Y = (X - X1) / (X2 - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) + Y1;
```

For integer math formula A performs better as long as multiplication `(X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1)` result stays with in range of the type. Formula B won't work, because if `X1 <= X <= X2`, then division will always equal `0`.

For floating point both should work, but I'm thinking that B would offer better accuracy since multiplication result will remain smaller.

1. Is my assumption about floating point accuracy correct?
2. Is there some floating point quirk that I am not taking into consideration?

Assume IEEE 754 floating point representation.

Note 1: I am interested in floating point case, integer math is pretty straight forward.

Note 2: Variables on FP formula may have non-integer values, but NaN and Infs are not within the scope of the question.

Comment: Please specify: Is your interest with points that have floating-point values or only integer ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, multiplications and divisions rarely cause a significant loss of precision. Because these are *floating point* numbers, with separate fields for the scale and significant digits, getting large intermediate results in itself isn't an issue. `2e100/3e100` and `2/3` are (for all intents and purposes) equally accurate.

On the other hand, additions or subtractions with a result much smaller in magnitude than the operands are much more common causes of loss of precision.

With this in mind, the two forms are basically equivalent. If your numbers are 'mainstream' (i.e. multiplication doesn't cause over/underflow), then you won't encounter any problems with either form. If you can't assume your numbers are mainstream, then you have to take all kinds of special precautions to get a good result.

Now, rather than consider the two forms (A) and (B), I would suggest selecting between (A) and (C):

```
Y = (X - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) + Y1; (A)
Y = (X - X2) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1) + Y2; (C)
```

and choosing the form for which the first factor `X - X1` or `X - X2` is smaller in magnitude. That way, if `Y` turns out to be small, you minimize the loss of precision.

For example, let's use

```
(X1,Y1) = (-100, -100)
(X2,Y2) = (0, 0)
X = 0.76
```

with three digits of precision. Then we get for (A):

```
Y = (0.76 - -100) * (0 - -100) / (0 - -100) + -100
  = 101 * 100 / 100 - 100
  = 1
```

while for (C), we get:

```
Y = (0.76 - 0) * (0 - -100) / (0 - -100) + 0
  = 0.76 * 100 / 100 + 0
  = 0.76
```

So, the quick answer to your question is:

1. Size of intermediate results in itself doesn't matter. It is not a reason to prefer (B) over (A).
2. Always consider addition and subtraction as more likely sources of loss of precision.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the below for `Y`

```
 X - X1    Y - Y1
------- = -------
X2 - X1   Y2 - Y1
```

Both (A) and (B) will behave similarity:

```
(A)    Y = (X - offsetX) * deltaY / deltaX + offsetY;
(B)    Y = (X - offsetX) / deltaX * deltaY + offsetY;
```

If points are originally whole numbers, "B ... multiplication result will remain smaller." may hold, but else-wise `|deltaX|` `|deltaY|` could both be less than 1 and then this assumption may fail.

To improve *accuracy*, consider the effects of subtracting 2 numbers (or adding 2 similar numbers that differ in sign).  Code could choose `X1,Y1` or `X2,Y2` as the offset by reversing the roles of point1 and point2.  **Choosing the offset closest to X,Y will improve accuracy**.

With FP math, `*` and `/` stress the exponential range allowable by the FP number: The precision of the product can be expected to be within a bit of the mathematically correct answer, but range may overflow.

`+` and `-` stress the precision: The range is rarely an issue, but there may be large cancellation in the significands used to form the sum.

---

If all co-ordinate values originally are integers, recommend using a 2x wide integer math and deriving the best answer.

If the final result is to be integer-ized, insure code uses a `iy = (int) round(Y);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no underflow or overflow occurs, they should be roughly equivalent in terms of accuracy: both multiplication and division will incur the same relative error, and as the error is roughly multiplicitive, the order in which you perform the operations won't make much difference.

If you know something about the relative magnitudes of the terms involved, you might be able to rearrange terms such that the subtractions are exact, which might reduce the error slightly.

Comment: Are you saying that multiplication/division will never be problem, but addition/subtraction will? (Excluding any overflow situations of course)

Comment: No merely that in some cases it is possible to do the subtraction exactly, e.g. see Theorem 11 in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Also be careful with the final addition: in certain cases, you could get catastrophic cancellation.