# Given three `double` values `x`, `y` and `z`, how to minimize the precision loss of calculating `x * y / z`?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I have three `double` values `x`, `y` and `z`, and I want to calculate the result of `x * y / z`, I can write the following functions:

```c
double mul_div_1(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x * y / z;
}

double mul_div_2(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x * (y / z);
}
```

The problem is that neither function gives the most accurate result at all times. For example:

- If `x = 0.1`, `y = 0.1`, `z = 0.1`,

  - `mul_div_1(x, y, z)` gives me `0.10000000000000002`,
  - `mul_div_2(x, y, z)` gives me `0.1`.
- If `x = 23.0`, `y = 13.0`, `z = 23.0`,

  - `mul_div_1(x, y, z)` gives me `13.0`,
  - `mul_div_2(x, y, z)` gives me `12.999999999999998`.

Is there a way to minimize the precision lost at calculating `x * y / z`? You can assume `isfinite(x) && isfinite(y) && isfinite(z) && z != 0.0`.

The precision loss need not to be absolutely minimal, having a way to select a best result between:

- `x * y / z`
- `(x / z) * y`
- `x * (y / z)`

is good enough for me.

Comment: It's not going to make much difference.  They're all going to have errors.  Keep in mind that a constant like `0.1` has no exact representation, so in that case you're going to have errors right from the start.  Rather than trying to obtain exact results, just round your results when displaying them, or define some kind of error tolerance value.

Comment: @TomKarzes I am aware of the inexactness of `0.1`, and I am OK with it. I just want some kind of strategy that does some kind of proper precision protection, no need to achieve absolute minimal precision loss.

Comment: @TomKarzes Also, the precession loss will make a difference if the intermediate result overflows. For example, If I have `x = 1e200`, `y = 1e200`, `z = 1e200`, `x * y / z` give me infinity, and `x * (y / z)` gives me `1e200`. I consider infinity and `1e200` are different enough.

Comment: If your data can vary by 200 orders of magnitude, perhaps `double` is not the right data type for you.

Comment: Similar question, although not a duplicate: [Retaining maximum possible accuracy on float interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27899609/694733)

Comment: @EFanZh Yes, if there's a risk of overflow or underflow of the intermediate values, then you may need to order your operations to avoid it.  But that is strongly dependent on the actual data values, so they would need to be taken into account to avoid that.  You could even make a quick check up front to determine if a particular evaluation order might overflow, then do one of several things depending on the result of that check.

Comment: Re “I have three `double` values `x`, `y` and `z`, and I want to calculate the value of `a * b / c`”: It is not possible to calculate `a * b / c` given `x`, `y`, and `z`. Would you care to rephrase that?

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about precision loss (not over-/underflows), you can calculate the product with higher precision, using fused-multiply-addition (`fma`), and manually do a long division on that:

```
#include <math.h>
double mul_div(double x, double y, double z)
{
    double xy = x*y;    // higher bits of product
    double xy_ = fma(x, y, -xy); // remaining bits of product

    double q = xy / z;  // higher bits of quotient

    double r= xy_ + fma(-q, z, xy); // remainder of division, added to lower part of product
    q += r / z;    // add quotient of remainder
    return q;
}
```

If you also have to handle over-/underflows, you could first separate your numbers into exponent and a normalized fraction using `frexp`, do `mul_div` on the fractions and add/subtract the exponents, then re-compose the number using `ldexp`.

Comment: In the absence of underflow/overflow, this delivers results with maximum error ~= 0.5 ulp If division is slow, one could use instead: `double mul_div (double x, double y, double z)
{
 double ph, pl, qh, ql, d, r;
 ph = x * y;
 pl = fma (x, y, -ph);
 r  = 1 / z;
 qh = ph * r;
 d  = fma (z, -qh, ph);
 qh = fma (r, d, qh);
 ql = fma (z, -qh, ph);
 ql = ql + pl;
 d  = ql * r;
 ql = fma (z, -d, ql);
 ql = fma (r, ql, d);
 return qh + ql;
}
`

Comment: @njuffa Fair enough - comment removed.

Answer (score 2):

> The precision loss need not to be absolutely minimal

For the examples you gave, the max loss of precision is one bit.

---

x=0.1 y=0.1 z=0.1

|  | Hex/Binary/Decimal |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0X1.999999999999AP-4 0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 |
| (x*y)/z | 0X1.999999999999BP-4 0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011011 0.10000000000000001942890293094023945741355419158935546875 |
| (x/z)*y | 0X1.999999999999AP-4 0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 |
| (y/z)*x | 0X1.999999999999AP-4 0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 |

Whichever approach you take, you're at most off by one bit.

---

x=23 y=13 z=23

|  | Hex/Binary/Decimal |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 0X1.A000000000000P+3 1101.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13 |
| (x*y)/z | 0X1.A000000000000P+3 1101.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13 |
| (x/z)*y | 0X1.A000000000000P+3 1101.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 13 |
| (y/z)*x | 0X1.9FFFFFFFFFFFFP+3 1100.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 12.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 |

Whichever approach you take, you're at most off by one bit.

---

For addition and subtraction, you you want to work with numbers of similar magnitude. But there's no such constraint for multiplication and division. You simply have to watch out for overflows and underflows.

Comment: Event if there are no overflows, is it guarantted to get off by most one bit for any values?

Comment: I didn't say that. The point is that you have failed to identify a problem. Also, see the section at the bottom.

Comment: But thinking about it more, working with same-magnitude numbers matters for addition and subtraction, but I think it's not relevant for multiplication and division.

Comment: Maybe the criterion is to avoid getting an intermediate value very close to or very far from 0.

Comment: @nieslon, nah, it really doesn't matter for multiplication and division. As you can see from the following, the difference in magnitudes (i and j) are irrelevant: ( x * 2^i ) * ( y * 2^j ) = ( x * y ) * 2 ^ ( i + j ).  Aside from overflows and underflows, of course.

Comment: @EFanZh for IEEE arithmetic the result is guaranteed to be within a single bit for a single operation. But of course you're doing two operations.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few special cases:

- `fabs(x) == fabs(z)`, determine the sign and return a perfect `y` or `-y`.
- `fabs(y) == fabs(z)`, determine the sign and return a perfect `x` or `-x`.
- the sum of used bits (or the total bits minus the trailing zero bits) in the significands of `x` and `y` is less than or equal to the number of bits in a significand; and therefore the multiplication will not cause precision loss and should be done first (because doing the division first will probably cause avoidable precision loss in the multiplication). For example, 1.5 is 2 bits (1.1 in binary) and 1.0625 is 4 bits (1.001 in binary), and 2+4 = 6 bits, which will fit in a 53-bit significand without any precision loss.
- `x` or `y` is a multiple of `z`; and doing the corresponding division first reduces precision loss in the multiplication.

Apart from those cases (and likely instead of those cases) the easiest option is to just use something bigger for the calculation - either unpack into "sign, significand, exponent" integers and do the maths yourself with integers, or 80-bit extended precision (maybe `long double` if you're lucky) or `__float128`, or pairs of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to minimize the precision loss of calculating `a * b / c` where `a`, `b` and `c` are all `double` types?

**Without resorting to higher precision math**

The `*` product and `/` quotient, when not exactly the same as infinite math, each step will be a little higher or lower - depending on rounding mode.

With the common *round to nearest, ties to even* mode, The result will be ≤ 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of the best possible answer.

Given two operations, the max expected error is then within 1.5 ULP. [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745561/given-three-double-values-x-y-and-z-how-to-minimize-the-precision-loss/75748792?noredirect=1#comment133630589_75748792).

There *might* be a corner case when the (intermediate) result is near a power-of-two, that the 2 steps (either `*` then `/` or `/` then `*`) will result in 2.0 ULP.

Use either `mul_div_1()` or `mul_div_2()`, with a slight preference to the first.  Multiplication is exact when the significant digits in `a, b` are few, unlike so many divisions, so code only risks 1 rounding.

**With higher precision math**

When `long double` is higher precision than `double`:

```
double mul_div_1(double x, double y, double z) {
    return (long double) x * y / z;
}
```

**Test if one of the 2 paths is error free**

Although `fmod(y,z) == 0` is not a 100% guarantee test to detect if the division will be exact, it is close.

```
#include <math.h>
double mul_div_3(double x, double y, double z) {
  if (fmod(y,z) == 0) {
    puts("x * (y / z)");
    return x * (y / z);
  }
  puts("x * y / z");
  return x * y / z;
}

#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, mul_div_3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
  printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, mul_div_3(23, 13, 23));
}
```

Output

```
x * (y / z)
0.10000000000000001
x * y / z
13
```

Comment: Re "Given two operations, the max expected error is then within 1.0 ULP" That is too optimistic, it works more like compound interest. Without resorting to math with error bounds, it it easily demonstrated (not proof, of course) by running numerous random test vectors that the maximum error for `mul_div_1()` and `mul_div_2()` in the question is *1.5 ulp*.